# NetSuite Advanced PDF/HTML Rich text rendering - unexpected error

Tags: netsuite

I have got a field defined as a rich text field and that's causing any unexpected error when printing picking tickets. Looks like there is a problem parsing rich-text fields on advanced PDF/HTML templates.

I have seen the suggestions to use third-party tools to render the rich text context without disturbing the formatting. I am not concerned about the formatting as long as the content is readable.

Any ideas, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the field in a [CDATA](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect) section.

For example; `<![CDATA[${item.description}]]>`